# Dejar activa una opción del menú en html y css

Tags: html, css

Estoy trabajando con un menú, el cual tiene las opciones de INICIO, REGISTRAR y MOSTRAR, cuando paso el cursor esas opciones cambian de color, eso funciona bien, lo que quiero hacer es que cuando entre a una de estas opciones permanezca el color, ya que al momento de dar click y entrar el color se quita, e intentado con la propiedad active en CSS pero no me funciona, aqui anexo mi código.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Inicio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="navbar.css">
</head>
<body>

<header>
    <div class="row">
        <a href="home.php"></href></ahref><img src="imagenes/logo.png" alt="Logo-INE"></a>
        <ul class="main-nav">
            <?php if ($_SESSION['level'] == 1 || $_SESSION ['level'] == 2):?>
                <li><a href="home.php">INICIO</a></li>
                <li><a href="registrociudadanos.php">REGISTRAR</a></li>
                <li><a href="mostrar.php">MOSTRAR</a></li>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <li><?php echo $_SESSION["name"];?></li>
            <li><a href="salir.php">SALIR</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</header>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
header {
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: white;
    height: 10vh ;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    padding: auto;
    color: darkgrey;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: "Lucida Sans";
    border-bottom: #880e4f  2px solid;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.main-nav {
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 30px;
    display: block;
}

.main-nav li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.main-nav li a {
    color: darkgrey;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    display: block;
    font-family: "Lucida Sans";
    font-size: 15px;

}
.main-nav li a:active {
    color: #c2185b;
}

.main-nav li a:hover {
    color: #c2185b;
}

img {
    width: 180px;
    height: auto;
    float: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Espero esto sea lo que buscas amigo

La idea es usar en este caso **jquery** para ejecutar un evento `click` y al elemento que instancia agregarle la clase y a todos los demás quitársela

```js
$(".ul").find("li").click(function(){
  $(".ul li").removeClass('estas')
  $(this).addClass('estas')
})
```

```css
ul li {
  padding:10px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.estas {
  background: rgb(68, 160, 185);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="ul">
    <li class="estas"><a href="#">boton1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">boton2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">boton3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">boton4</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Si, es algo a si, lo intendo adaptar a mi codigo pero no me funciona

Comment: cuando haces click en un botón (`li`) cambias de url? osea cargas otra pagina o es un link interno?

Comment: Si, cambio de url

Comment: a bueno amigo la solución es agregarle la case al botón en donde te encuentras ubicado

Comment: osea en cada pagina que tengas el menu pones la clase de ejemplo `estas` para agregar los atributos necesarios

Answer (score 0):

Al ser enlaces a páginas nuevas cada vez, lo mas sencillo es que a cada enlace de la página al crearla le coloques la clase con el color que quieras tener por ejemplo

```
<li class="activa"><a href="home.php">INICIO</a></li>
```

Otra opción por si estas trabajando con plantillas y no quieres modificar una a una sería

```
<?php
$pagina=array_pop(explode("/",$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]));
$pagina2=explode("?",$pagina);
?>
```

Con este código sabes en la página que estas trabajando

En los enlaces haces una condicional

```
<li <?php if ($pagina2=="home.php"){class="activa" }><a href="home.php">INICIO</a></li>
```